# Delete Sheets With No Color, Remove Comments from All Sheets, Break Links to All Sources

Tags: excel, vba, modeling, financial

I am currently working on my first ever VBA macro to run the functions described in the title. I currently have the following code.

It appears to be working as intended, but I would love a second set of eyes to tell me if I have any unintended consequences or if there are more stable ways to write this. Thanks in advance, KP.

```
'
' deletecomments Macro
' delete comments, removetabs, break links for rolling models
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+alt+R
'
Public Sub RollModel()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cmt As Comment

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each cmt In ws.Comments
cmt.Delete
Next cmt
Next ws

   On Error Resume Next
   For Each it In ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
       For Each sh In Sheets
         sh.Cells.Replace it, ""
          For Each cl In sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(-4174)
             If InStr(cl.Validation.Formula1, "#REF") Then cl.Validation.Delete
          Next
       Next
       ThisWorkbook.BreakLink it, 1
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Sht As Worksheet

For Each Sht In Worksheets
    If Sht.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then Sht.Delete
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not that this answers your question in anyway, but you might want to stick `Option Explicit` before your code. What purpose does the `On error resume next` serve here?

Comment: Have you tried `Range.Clearcomments` instead of looping through every comment? E.g. `for each ws in activeworkbook.worksheets: ws.cells.clearcomments: next ws`

Comment: Sorry a lot of this code is mashed together from other SO posts and forums as I am still new to VBA, so somethings may be in there with no function in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am sure someone else can give you a better answer, but these are just some things I noticed.

- Undeclared variables are being treated as variants
- On error resume next will suppress all errors -- not just the one you are trying to ignore
- `Sheets` collection can include Chart sheets if any exist in your workbook, whereas `Worksheets` do not.

Also, sorry for bad formatting. Written on mobile. Untested.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RollModel()

With thisworkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In .Worksheets
Ws.cells.clearcomments
Next ws

' I assume your on error resume next was because when there are no LinkSources, vbempty is returned instead of an array -- which you can't iterate over '

' Also, this method can also return a 2 dimensional array according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources -- which would cause an error as array indexes below are one-dimensional '

Dim linkArray as variant
Linkarray = .linksources

Dim linkIndex as long
Dim cell as range

If not isempty(linkarray) then

For linkIndex = Lbound(linkarray) to ubound(linkarray)

For Each ws In .Worksheets

Ws.cells.replace linkarray(linkIndex), ""

For Each cell In ws.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
If InStr(cell.Validation.Formula1, "#REF") Then
cl.Validation.Delete ' Not sure if this is the best way/approach, so have not really changed it.'
End if
Next cell

Next ws

.BreakLink linkarray(linkIndex), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

Next linkIndex

End if

For Each ws In .Worksheets

If ws.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next ws

End With

End Sub
```